# Conditionally display field based on comparison to other field

Tags: 8, theming

I have a content type Event that has a startdate (field_eventdate) and an optional enddate (field_eventend).
Although it's optional, the enddate is often filled in by the users with the same date as the startdate.
So I want to hide the enddate if it's equal to the startdate or display it on the same line as the startdate when it's different.

e.g.

```
2020-02-02 10:00
Here comes more text for a single day event
```

and

```
2020-02-02 10:00 - 2020-02-03 16:00
Here is more text for a multiday event
```

So far I managed to delete the enddate from the render array when it's equal:

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_node__event(&$variables) {
  $startdate = $variables['content']['field_eventdate'][0]['#markup'];
  $enddate = $variables['content']['field_eventend'][0]['#markup'];

  if ($startdate === $enddate) {
    unset($variables['content']['field_eventend']);
  }
  else {
    // add an &em-dash; so the dates are nicely spaced
    $variables['content']['field_eventend'][0]['#markup'] = " — " . $enddate;
    // add float-left to the start date so they end up on the same line
    // TODO: what goes here?
  }
}
```

But I cannot find out how to notice in a twig template that I have a startdate and an enddate and therefore add 'float' css classes to put them in line.

I have tried to add a special attribute to the 'field_eventdate' field, and add a 'float-left' class in the twig template for the field, but the custom attribute gets lost somewhere.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this have to be done on preprocessing level ?  Perhaps you can use https://www.drupal.org/project/fico ?  Have you tried ?

Comment: @GiorgosK Thanks for the suggestion. It sounds like an interesting module, but is has a dependency in Display Suite, which I don't intend to use.

Comment: I looked into it some more and from my first attempts I found: I need to build a plugin (which is beyond my skill set) that does what my preprocess function already does and I still have no solution for the inline problem. Note: the DS dependency hasn't thrown an error so far with v1.0.

Comment: Using what you have already done, you can check in the twig template if the field exists and if it does you can add the classes you want to use. {% if content.field_eventend %} --print the field with wanted classes-- {% endif %}

Comment: Thanks @MikeChris. Which twig template? I created a template `field--field-eventdate.html.twig` but I cannot find if field_eventend exists. I prefer to fall back to the default templates as much as possible, so I don't want to create a `node--event.html.twig` if possible. Can I set a custom attribute on the field_eventdate in the preprocess function? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by adding a template for the content type. This allowed me to simplify the preprocess function:

```php
function mytheme_preprocess_node__event(&$variables) {
  $startdate = $variables['content']['field_eventdate'][0]['#markup'];
  $enddate = $variables['content']['field_eventend'][0]['#markup'];

  if ($startdate === $enddate) {
    unset($variables['content']['field_eventend']);
  }
}
```

I then copied the `node.html.twig` template to `node--event.html.twig`. I only changed the main `{{ content }}` part into:

```
    {{ content.field_tags }}
    {{ content.field_eventlocation }}
    <div class="event_dates clearfix">
      {{ content.field_eventdate }}
      {% if content.field_eventend %}
        &nbsp;&ndash; {{ content.field_eventend }}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    {{ content|without('field_tags', 'field_eventlocation', 'field_eventdate', 'field_eventend') }}
```

This replaced my attempt to create and modify `field--field-eventdate.html.twig` template.

Maybe this is not the best option, but at least it works.